# OutOfMemory exception thrown while writing large text file

Tags: c#, text, out-of-memory, file-writing

I want to generate a string and then write it in to a .txt file. The problem is I get OutOfMemory exceptions when I attempt to do so.

The file is large (about 10000 lines).

I use `String.Format` and loops to create the string. How can I write this to a .txt file?

```
        string Text= @"...";
        const string channelScalar = @"...";
        Text= string.Format(...);
        foreach (Channel channel in ...)
        {
            switch (channel.Type)
            {
                case "...":
                    Text= string.Format(Text,
                        ChannelFrames(channel, string.Format(...);
                    break;
            }
        }
        File.WriteAllText(textBox9.Text,Text);
```

Comment: Use a streamwriter and write each line directly instead of storing the whole thing in memory first.

Comment: Please provide your code so that we know how you are generating the string.  If you aren't already using `TextWriter` and `StreamWriter`, you may need to use them.

Comment: thanks ill look for streamwriter. @Jens

Comment: Cut your example down please to something that is representative, the actual logic to calculate the intermittent strings is just noise for the underlying problem. Also note that you are going to thrash on the GC really hard by doing this without at least a `StringBuffer` as `string` objects are immutable and so require copying. The total memory required to append is roughly quadratic, so 10,000 lines takes about 50 million times as much memory as one line. However what they said about using a `Stream` is certainly the best solution, as you don't need to store the whole string at all.

Comment: i did write the code. where to put stream writer? @maniak1982

Comment: Look at the solution provided below by @Jens.  Instead of appending to the string, write directly to the StreamWriter.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a `StreamWriter` to directly write each line you generate into the textfile. This avoids storing the whole long file in memory first.

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\Somewhere\\whatever.txt")) 
    {
        //Generate all the single lines and write them directly into the file
        for (int i = 0; i<=10000;i++)
        {
            sw.WriteLine("This is such a nice line of text. *snort*");
        }
    }
```

Comment: its amazing. file saved under 1 sec. thank you very much! @Jens