# Retrieving results and place in a .csv format with lazy loading and gzip the file

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, csv, parallel-processing

I am trying to download tables from sql server and write each downloaded table to a csv file and then gzip it.

My problem now is that the table is so large (1 million lines above and I was using python pandas dataframe to do it),  that it gives memory error.

Is there a way to do this lazily in C# so that the memory usage is minimized, and then I can run 2-3 processes in parallel for this task?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and yes.

1. You have to retrieve data in a loop to ensure that you are not holding all that million records in a memory. Use StreamWriter to write lines into file instead of holding them in memory: [OutOfMemory exception thrown while writing large text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30536982/outofmemory-exception-thrown-while-writing-large-text-file)
2. Create your software so that writing method takes table name as parameter. Then you can run all the tables parallel if you want to. Use separate files for database tables to ensure faster performance. If you want to perform database writings as separate handleable threads, use thread start: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x4c42hc(v=vs.110).aspx

   Or make that writing async and call it with await keyword. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193364(v=vs.110).aspx